# Updating / Inserting row only if it's different from current value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a desktop app that sends a Data Table containing information about a product to a SQL Server db. I want to update the table only for the columns that differ from the received row. I'm wondering what's the proper way to:

- check if the value in the received Data Table is different than the value in actual db table, and if it is then update the table
- if the value was modified then insert a new row into a table containing logs

What I currently do:

I select the current value from the datable inside a new variable (@OldValue) and then compare it against the received value (@NewValue). If the values are different I just update the column and insert a new record into the log table.

```
DECLARE @ProductId = 333
IF @OldValue <> @NewValue
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.ProductTable
       SET Column1 = @NewValue
    WHERE
       ProductId = @ProductId




 INSERT INTO 
     dbo.Logs
 VALUES
     (@ProductId, @ModifiedColumn, @OldValue, @NewValue, GETDATE())

END
```

I run the check for every column that needs to be updated (if the data has changed), but the received Data Table contains about 15 columns and I think there must be a more elegant solution to the problem.

Any useful tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your table only have 1 column that is being updated here? Your log table and `UPDATE` imply that only `Column` is being updated; correct?

Comment: No, the target and the source table both contain 15 columns that contain such data as ProductId, ProductName, ProductPrice and so on @Larnu

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled 2012

Comment: Are you able to do any preprocessing on the client? Send back only those rows which have changed. You could use a trigger to update the log file instead of a separate script.

Comment: @PeterSmith I only send 1 row, but 15 different columns and unfortunately a trigger is a no go for me

Comment: Off the wall idea; convert all values to nvarchar for the current and new rows - create a function to do it -  and create a checksum of each - if they are different so it the data! See [here](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/sql-fastest-way-to-compare-multiple-column-values) for just this idea plus variants.

Comment: Sounds like a trigger is best option here. Since you are talking about single row updates it will be less of a performance hit to just update the row the "new" values. Then have an update trigger that looks at the values of the inserted and deleted virtual tables and insert to your logging table if at least one of the columns changed. Or you could abandon doing this manually and implement Change Data Capture.

Comment: "I have a desktop app that sends a Data Table..." Does this means that your procedure is taking in a table valued parameter?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, exactly

Comment: Well, the `update` shouldn't be a problem to do, even if nothing have changed, so I'm guessing the main problem is how to populate the logs table, is that correct?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yeah, the update part is not a problem. The problem is that I need the correct data to fill the log table with (column name of the column that has changed, it's old value and new value). I don't really want to use triggers, since there are other systems that also modify the data within the table and it would just cause a complete mess.

Comment: is the row in a table valued parameter or is it sent as 15 different input params?

Comment: @MartinSmith It's a single table valued parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like the below. This only caters for two columns currently but it should be clear how to add additional ones in.

```
DECLARE @UpdateResult TABLE
(
ProductId INT PRIMARY KEY,
dCol1 VARCHAR(50), /*These should be whatever the datatype of the relevant columns in dbo.Logs are*/
iCol1 VARCHAR(50), 
dCol2 VARCHAR(50), 
iCol2 VARCHAR(50)
);


UPDATE PT
SET PT.Col1 = Tvp.Col1, 
    PT.Col2 = Tvp.Col2 
    OUTPUT inserted.ProductId, 
           deleted.Col1, 
           inserted.Col1 ,
           deleted.Col2, 
           inserted.Col2 INTO @UpdateResult(ProductId, dCol1, iCol1, dCol2,iCol2 )
FROM dbo.ProductTable AS PT
JOIN @Tvp Tvp ON Tvp.ProductId = PT.ProductId
/*Only update where at least one column is different*/
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PT.Col1, PT.Col2 
              EXCEPT 
              SELECT Tvp.Col1, Tvp.Col2)


INSERT INTO dbo.Logs
SELECT ProductId, ModifiedColumn, OldValue, NewValue, getdate()
FROM @UpdateResult
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
                    ('Col1',dCol1, iCol1),
                    ('Col2',dCol2, iCol2)
            ) unpvt(ModifiedColumn, OldValue, NewValue )
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT OldValue EXCEPT SELECT NewValue)
```

Comment: I'll take a look at your solution and let u know later, thanks ;)

Comment: This does the job. Thank you~!

Answer (score 1):

I see this kind of problematic regulary. In most case, we concatenate all columns, separated by a fixed string like `'||'` and then we apply the `HASHBYTES('MD5',MyConcatenatedValue)` function for both tables. If the Hash is the same, we don't update the row. If it is different, we update it...

If I reuse your code, it could be comething like that :

```
DECLARE @ProductId = 333
SET @OldValue =     SELECT(HASHBYTES('MD5',Column1+'||'+Column2+'||'+Column3+'||'+Column4+'||'+Column5+'||'+Column6) FROM dbo.ProductTable) -- continue this logic for each column
SET @NewValue =     SELECT(HASHBYTES('MD5',Column1+'||'+Column2+'||'+Column3+'||'+Column4+'||'+Column5+'||'+Column6) FROM dbo.SourceTable) -- I assume you have a table with new values stored
IF @OldValue <> @NewValue
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product 
    FROM dbo.ProductTable Product
    INNER JOIN dbo.SourceTable Source 
       ON Product.ProductId = Source.ProductId
       SET Product.Column1 = Source.Column1
          ,Product.Column2 = Source.Column2
          ,Product.Column3 = Source.Column3
          ,Product.Column4 = Source.Column4
          ,Product.Column5 = Source.Column5
          ,Product.Column6 = Source.Column6              
    WHERE
      ProductId = @ProductId
END
```

However, you can't easily log wich column as been replaced because you make one check for all columns. Maybe you should consider implementing Temporal tables. Here is an article about it :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

I hope it helps, tell me if you need more details.

Comment: insightful, but sadly does not answer the question :(

Comment: I might have misunderstood but you wanted to know a elegant solution to check if you need to update a line with 15+ columns. I just gave you the best practice used in analytics domain. I would appreciate to know what I missed concerning your question. Do you need the code directly ?

Comment: I didn't ask the question -- I was trying to be helpful to a new user about why there were not upvotes :)   Yes, I think at least an example of how to do this with actual SQL code would be useful.  You outlined a strategy not a solution.

Comment: Ok I understand better now. I tried to add a concrete example based on some speculations. Thank you for your help and your feedback. :-)

Comment: Yes this now gets a +1 from me